# Postgresql connection with Struts 2/Hibernate/Maven and Spring

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, maven, struts2

I followed a tutorial to create a project with Struts 2, Maven, Hibernate and Spring with a Mysql database : http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-spring-hibernate-integration-example/

It's working and I would like to use a Postgresql database now. For that I edited somes configurations files to remove the mysql configuration by postgresql :

- in the pom.xml :

> ```
> <dependency>
> <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
> <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
> <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

- in the database.properties :

> ```
> jdbc.driverClassName=com.postgresql.jdbc.Driver
> jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my_base
> jdbc.username=...
> jdbc.password=...
> ```

- in HibernateSessionFactory.xml :

> `<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>`

And here is the error in Eclipse :

> GRAVE: Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé
>   (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener)
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/classes/config/spring/DataSource.xml]: Error
>   setting property values; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested
>   PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are: PropertyAccessException 1:
>   org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property
>   'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class
>   [com.postgresql.jdbc.Driver]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1279)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414) Caused
>   by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested
>   PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are: PropertyAccessException 1:
>   org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property
>   'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class
>   [com.postgresql.jdbc.Driver]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:104)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:59)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1276)

Where is the problem ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Struts2 is highly unlikely to play a role in the configuration/solution to this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Could not load JDBC driver class [com.postgresql.jdbc.Driver] at
```

I believe the correct class name is `org.postgresql.Driver`